# How to query a date/time field using pothos with prisma and postgresql

Tags: postgresql, graphql, prisma

I've got my pothos set up using Prisma and postgresql. I'm trying to expose the createdAt and updatedAt fields from prisma in my builder:

Prisma schema:

```
model Course {
  id          Int      @id @unique @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt   DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt   DateTime @updatedAt
  // removed fields for brevity. 
}
```

My builder:

```
builder.prismaObject('Course', {
  fields: (t) => ({
    id: t.exposeID('id'),
    createdAt: t.expose('createdAt', {
      type: 'DateTime' as any,
    })
  })
})
```

I have also tried this way:

```
builder.prismaObject('Course', {
      fields: (t) => ({
        id: t.exposeID('id'),
        createdAt: t.expose('createdAt', {
          type: Date, // simply set this as a Date type
        })
      })
    })
```

These two ways causes the same/similar error:

```
- error node_modules/@pothos/core/esm/config-store.js (210:18) @ ConfigStore.onTypeConfig
- error Error [PothosSchemaError]: Ref DateTime has not been implemented
```

I've also tried this which works, but obviously hacky (I don't want to leave it this way):

```
// @ts-ignore
    createdAt: t.exposeString('createdAt', {
      type: Date
    })
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out. The fix is a bit long, but I had to add the following library:

```
npm i graphql-scalars
```

Builder.ts this may be very case specific, but this is how I set it up:

```
import { DateTimeResolver} from "graphql-scalars";
// ... other code you may have here

export const builder = new SchemaBuilder<{
  PrismaTypes: PrismaTypes,
  Context: ReturnType<typeof createContext>, // add the scalar type below
  Scalars: {
    Date: {
      Input: Date;
      Output: Date;
    };
  };
}>({
  plugins: [PrismaPlugin, RelayPlugin, WithInputPlugin],
  relayOptions: {},
  prisma: {
    client: prisma,
  }
})

... other code
builder.queryType({


fields: (t) => ({
    ok: t.boolean({
      resolve: () => true,
    }),
  }),
});

// define your scalar type using the DateTimeResolver

builder.addScalarType("Date", DateTimeResolver, {});
```

Now you create your prisma object in whatever file you're adding the Date type field:

```
builder.prismaObject('Course', {
  fields: (t) => ({
    id: t.exposeID('id'),
    ...
    Lesson: t.relation('lessons'),
    createdAt: t.expose('createdAt', { // use the Date scalary type you defined here...
      type: 'Date',
    }),
    updatedAt: t.expose('updatedAt', {
      type: 'Date',
    })
  })
```